# Разместить анимационную рекламу у себя на сайте

Tags: jquery, html, css

Хочу попробовать разместить анимационную рекламу у себя на сайте, но не знаю как ее сделать! Пример: на одном и том же  слайде с начало появляется машина, следом над машиной прописывается текст,  потом с правой стороны от машины появляется цена или другая машина, следом машина мигает фарами и все это повторяется заново(цикл)! Мои познания в jquery упираются в слайд-шоу. С чего начать не знаю. Подскажите, может есть толковая ссылка или пример?

Comment: да, есть: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: А как называются эти рекламные ролики?

Comment: @Arty21 баннерами. Нет какого-то "однозначного" решения, есть только выбор технологии, можно вместо jquery + html/css взять canvas или flash, более конкретно сложно что-то сказать.